# Use VHDL entity with array ports in a systemverilog testbench in Vivado 2018

Tags: vhdl, simulation, system-verilog, vivado

I have two entities on a systemverilog testbench. One of them provides several 32 bit vectors and I need to connect them as an array of vectors to the other entity.  I created a register on the systemverilog testbench `reg [31:0] fifo_D[0:7];` but no matter what permutation of the reg I create I get an error,
ERROR: [VRFC 10-717] formal port array_data of type array_t does not match with actual type reg. In a VHDL package I have `type array_t is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);`

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be a limitation of the tool. Please check the user manual of what types they support between the language boundaries.

Comment: I'm still unsure if there is a good way to do this but after spending WAY to much time working on it I finally bit the bullet and made a VHDL wrapper for my VHDL entity and expanded the array out into a huge vector. I replaced the original entity in my systemverilog with the wrapper and its working. This is a band aid as opposed to a solution... if there is a solution.